# Subconsulta retorna mais de um valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, cte, union-all

Boa noite!

Tenho uma consulta sql baseado numa CTE e quero pegar o maior valor entre uma subconsulta, porém quando executo a consulta principal o erro de subconsulta retorna mais de um valor aparece. Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue código:

```
WITH CTE AS(
            SELECT TOP 1 PERSON.PERSON.FirstName AS NOME,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS A FROM PERSON.PERSON
        WHERE EmailPromotion = 0

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON.PERSON
        WHERE EmailPromotion = 1) AS EMAIL
        
        FROM PERSON.PERSON)SELECT MAX(EMAIL) FROM CTE
```

Comment: Tente explicar qual resultado deseja obter pois esta query está estranha. O subselect com UNION ALL retornará duas linhas a primeira com a quantidade total de registros da tabela PERSON.PERSON com EmailPromotion = 0 e a segunda com a quantidade com EmailPromotion = 1.

Comment: Eu desejo obter o maior valor entre EmailPromotion = 1 e EmailPromotion = 0. Eu fiz um union all para com base nisso pegar o maior valor (MAX)

Comment: Tentei colocar um TOP 1 mas não resolveu

Comment: Avalie o uso da função GREATEST destes COUNT.

Comment: No SQL SERVER não exite essa função. Sabe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Se quer o maior valor EmailPromotion (contagem) por pessoa (person) ? Dá um exemplo dos dados e da saída requerida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia,

Almino, se você quer obter o maior Count de EmailPromotion por pessoa, experimente fazer uns testes dessa forma:

```
WITH CTE_Count AS
(
  SELECT 
    FirstName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EmailPromotion = 0 THEN 1 END) AS EP0,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN EmailPromotion = 1 THEN 1 END) AS EP1
  FROM PERSON.PERSON
  GROUP BY
    FirstName
)

SELECT
  FirstName AS NOME,
  CASE WHEN EP0 > EP1 THEN EP0 ELSE EP1 END
FROM CTE_Count
```

Na CTE são feitas as contagens e na parte final da consulta é utilizado o Case para obter a maior contagem entre as 2.

Espero que ajude

Comment: Perfeito muito obrigado!